# there was an accident on dam neck road / there was an accident at dam neck road

Tags: prepositions

How do you determine when to use which proposition? (in on at...)

Its easy to say I'm sitting on a box or in a box

But sometimes its confusing

Like for example, do you say
-I'm in school
Or
-I'm at school

-there was an accident on this road
Or
-there was an accident at this road

Comment: *at* means the surroundings of the dam, and *on* means over the dam surface.

Answer (score 1):

**At** refers to a specific location, a *point* on the geography...

> ... **at** the intersection of Broad Street and Maple Avenue.

**On** refers to the road as a surface or as a route.

> There was some debris **on** the road.
>
> We are **on** the road that takes us into the city.

Thus, we cannot say <sup>not OK</sup> "there was an accident **at** the road"  <sup>not OK</sup> because the road is never a **point**.  The road is analogous to a line, straight or curvy.

P.S. But as Peter indicates in his answer, if you're traveling on Broad Street and reach Maple Avenue, where there is an accident *at the intersection*, you can say:

> There was an accident **at** Maple Avenue

But the sentence above requires the context that you were traveling on a road that intersects Maple Avenue; "at Maple Avenue" is there understood to mean "at the Maple Avenue intersection".

.

Answer (score 1):

Do you drive **on** the road or **at** the road?

> there was an accident **on** Dam Neck Road

means somewhere along that road

> there was an accident **at** Dam Neck Road

would mean you are already **on a different road** which **crosses** Dam Neck Road and the accident was where the two roads **intersect** *(as you point in the direction of Dam Neck Road)*

If there was a **specific location**

> There was an accident **at** Dam Neck Road and River Street

it would signify the location of the intersection

Additional examples

> There is an accident **on** highway 247
>   There is an accident **on** the bridge  *(this one is tricky)*
>   There is an accident **on** the off ramp **at** junction 64
>
> There is an accident **at** junction 64 **on** highway 247
>   There is an accident **at** the bridge  *(this one is tricky)*
>   There is an accident **at** the traffic light

Answer (score 0):

*In X* is appropriate if you are surrounded on most sides by X, such as *in* a container, building, etc.

*On X* is appropriate if you can physically be atop something, or to refer to flat surfaces.  Typically you are *on* a road.

*At X* is appropriate if X is a place.  The notion of a place is a logical construct and while usually associated to specific flat surfaces and buildings, it's a loose association - when we say *X is at Y* we don't care how X and Y are touching.

Some things can be both places and other things, so sometimes this distinction is blurry.  For example, school is a place, as well as a building.  So you can be *at school* or *in school*.

A road can be considered a place sometimes as well.  Typically this happens when an intersection is involved or one cares more about someone or something's location (or place) than the physical orientation against the road.